# Javascript and dynamic variable insertion

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic, insertion, document.write

Let's say I have am dynamically passing information to a variable in a URL like as shown below:

```
<script>

var ORDER = 200;
var QUANTITY = 1;
var EXTRA = [200,300,400];

var tag = document.write('<scr'+'ipt language="JavaScript" src="http://test.com/test/order.' + ORDER + '/quantity.' + QUANTITY"></scr' + 'ipt>');

</script>
```

Let's say I want to pass all the data in the EXTRA array... how would I do this?

I'm trying to get a URL that looks something like this after it is written to the page:

```
http://test.com/test/order.200/quantity.1/extra.200/extra.300/extra.400
```

(Passing the numbers to the same extra parameter in the URL is intentional, I need it to be passed in seperate instances but to the same variable)

I know I can use a for loop to cycle through the array.. how can I keep dynamically appending the numbers in the EXTRA array to the URL like in the example above?

Would something like this work?

```
for (i = 0; i < EXTRA.LENGTH; i++){
   tag.append(EXTRA[i]);
}
```

Please advise if you can,

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Dear friend, I think your problem is a different one. Why don't you use AJAX (eg. jQuery $.get) to send your params and get what you need?

Comment: Create your string before you pass it to `document.write`, then do normal string concatenation. There's no `.append()` method.

Comment: Tips: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice, 2. lowercase or cameCase for variables, uppercase represents CONSTANTS. 3. Double-check syntax highlighting in concatenation. 4. Forgot to declare `i`. 5. Encode your URL's.

Comment: In `document.write(............. + QUANTITY + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');` you missed `+ '` after `QUANTITY`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a question about joining items in an *Array*. *JavaScript* has [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) for this purpose, so you would want to do

```
var str = 'foo';
if (EXTRA.length) str += '/extra.' + EXTRA.join('/extra.');
str; // "foo/extra.200/extra.300/extra.400"
```